# Velocity Templating Language dealing with backslashes in input text

Tags: aws-api-gateway, velocity

**Problem Statement**

I'm in the process of writing an AWS API gateway and using Velocity Template Language (VTL) to transform my request into a structure that can be used by the backend. This has to be done on the API Gateway side since I have no control over the code that is calling the back, and the backend. The workflow is as follows:

-> legacy process sends request

-> API Gateway is invoked & transforms the request into a structure that is accepted by a lambda function

-> AWS lambda is invoked using transformed structure and returns a response

I have the template mostly figured out but there are a few niche cases surround special characters and I cannot find a solution that is universally able to resolve this.

**Code**

The transformation I have is as follows:

```
#set( $allParams = $input.params() )
#set( $InputBody = $util.escapeJavaScript($input.body) )
#set( $ParsedBody = $util.parseJson($input.body) )
#set( $text = $util.escapeJavaScript($ParsedBody.text) )
#set( $textString = $text.toString() )
#set( $text_language = $ParsedBody.language )
#set( $body = {
  "text": $textString,
  "categories": ["ALL"],
  "text_language": $text_language,
  "str_language_variants": ["en"]
})
#set($bodyString = $body.toString())
{
"body": "{\n  \"text\": \"$textString\",\n  \"text_language\": \"$text_language\",\n  \"str_language_variants\": [\"en\"], \n}",
}
}
```

**Test Cases**

1. The first test case has an inner `\"` which does not parse correctly

```
{
    "text": "besponsa sounds like \"famosa\" in spanish",
    "mode": "fb",
    "language": "en"
}
```

The error that I'm getting is:

Missing key arguments in the payloads ('text')

2. The second test case has a newline character in the text `\n` which with the above code is fine

```
{
    "text": "<i>Anxiety depression asthma Omicron</i> ad  \n asthma  anxiety, viagra, sildenafil, enzyme , mrtx1719",
    "mode": "all",
    "language": "en"
}
```

**Attempted Solution(s)**
The only solution that has shown promise for the first case is if add a `replace()` method into the `$textString` to be as follows:

```
"body": "{\n  \"text\": \"$textString\"... -> "body": "{\n  \"text\": \"$textString.replace("\", "\\\"),\"
```

But this fails when I run test case 2.

**Question**

Is there anyway of having the VTL parse for both special character types while maintaining as much of the code above?